# Cuda global __device__ variable auto initialization

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm declaring a global variable `myvar` on the device using the `__device__` specifier. I don't set it to a meaningful value anywhere (not using cudaMemcpyToSymbol in my kernel launch method, as you would normally do).

I'd expect the value of `myvar` to be random garbage, but it's neatly 0.0 every time. **Does CUDA do auto-initialisation of device variables?**

I've checked it using the CUDA debugger also, the value is effectively 0.

```
__device__ float myvar;

__global__ void kernel(){
    printf("my var: %f", myvar);
}

int kernel_launch(){
    kernel<<<1,5>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Based on my experience (not guaranteed), CUDA is interested in allocating the same memory segment to the same variable in different runs. I've observed pretty same garbage content over different CUDA debugging sessions for uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA does not automatically initialize any variables. It's just a CUDA implementation based coincidence that `myvar` becomes zero in your test app.

In IEEE-754 floating point (used by NVIDIA GPUs), an all zero pattern corresponds to 0.0, so it's a much more likely "random" value than, say, 1.0f.

Don't infer the values of all your GPU memory based on the value in that single word...

I did a small experiment and was slightly surprised by the result though. I initialized `myvar` with `__device__ float myvar(1.1f);` and altered the `printf()` so that it prints both the value and the address of the variable. Then I ran it, got `1.1f` output and noted the address. Then I removed the initialization and ran it again. This time, the value went back to `0.0f` while the address stayed the same, showing that the chunk of memory in which this variable is located does get zeroed out as part of regular CUDA operations. For instance, this could happen if the CUDA program is copied to the GPU within a fixed size chunk in which the other data is zero, and `myvar` is assigned to an address within this chunk.

Comment: Switched to debug build, and getting the same results (0.0)

Comment: I don't believe that second point about debug builds is correct

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I confused device with host debug behavior. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: So apparently GPU global memory is all zero. Why?

Comment: @JeroenBaert: Updated my answer with some more info.

Comment: @RogerDahl: I am struggling to parse that last paragraph. You say that not intialising anything yielded a value of 1.0f, and that shows that the memory does get *zeroed* by the runtime. How can zeroing a variable produce a value of 1.0f? Doesn't that mean that the value was set to 0x3DCCCCCD, and not 0x00000000?

Answer (score 0):

`__device__` uninitialized variables, much like their global `__host__` counterpart, need to be declared in the executable by their size and location in memory. As far as I know, such declarations always need a placeholder value, which unsurprisingly appears to be zero.

This can be checked readily. For example this command disassembles the output of a simple `__device__ int a;` declaration:

```
nvcc -o test.o -c -x cu - <<< "__device__ int a;" && cuobjdump -xelf all test.o && nvdisasm *cubin
```

You'll get the following output:

```
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_TEXMODE_UNIFIED EF_CUDA_64BIT_ADDRESS EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"


//--------------------- .nv.constant14            --------------------------
    .section    .nv.constant14,"a",@progbits
    .align  4
    .align      8
.nv.constant14:
        /*0000*/    .dword  a


//--------------------- .nv.global                --------------------------
    .section    .nv.global,"aw",@nobits
    .align  4
    .type       a,@object
    .size       a,(.L_1 - a)
a:
.nv.global:
    .zero       4
.L_1:
```

where you can clearly see the implicit zero initialization.

However, I believe it would be unsafe to rely on this.